# Estoy trabajando con un poco de javascript. Estoy cambiando los precios a una tarjeta al oprimir un boton toggle

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando con un poco de javascript. Estoy cambiando los precios a una tarjeta al oprimir un botón. Estoy utilizando toggle, pero cuando duplico la cantidad de tarjetas, la propiedad toggle me aplica solo al primero.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"       class="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox" class="switch">      </label> 
      <div class="card-toggle">
        <p>
          <span id="mensual" >&dollar;39.99</span>
          <span id="anual" >&dollar;399.99</span>
        </p>  
        <ul>
          <li>1 tb libre</li>
          <li>Más espacio en la nube</li>
          <li>ilimitado</li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="cards" >
      <div class="card-toggle">
        <p>
          <span id="mensual" >&dollar;59.99</span>
          <span id="anual" >&dollar;599.99</span>
        </p>  
        <ul>
          <li>1 tb libre</li>
          <li>Más espacio en la nube</li>
          <li>ilimitado</li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Mi css

```
#mensual{
    display block
  }
  #anual{
    display none
  }
  
  #mensual.active{
    display none
  }
  #anual.active{
    display block
  }
```

Lo que hago es quitarle y agregarle una clase 'active' con toggle, pero solo  me aplica a la primera card-toggle

```
const btnChek = document.querySelector('.checkbox'); 
btnChek.addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.getElementById('mensual').classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('anual').classList.toggle('active');
```

Comment: Sí, porque los IDs deben ser únicos y los estás repitiendo.

Comment: Estas indicando el mismo id (mensual y anual) para N elementos, la idea de los ids es que sean únicos para poder trabajar con ellos :)

Comment: entiendo, entoces tendria que hacer document.getElementById('mensual').classList.toggle('active'); con diferentes id, como puedo simplifcar ese codigo. Soy muy novato, disculpas

Comment: Podrias crear los elementos `span` dentro de un ciclo y de esa forma asignarles un id autoincremental por ejemplo

Answer (score 1):

Los IDs deben ser únicos, de lo contrario, el navegador tratará de "adivinar" cuál es el que quieres obtener. En su lugar, usa clases, para poder tener todos los elementos deseados en una colección con [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) que puedes recorrer con [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) para analizar o modificar.

Dentro de *forEach()* estoy usando [funciones flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions) para simplificar el código.

```js
// Definir primero todas las variables / constantes necesarias
const btnChek = document.querySelector('.checkbox');
// Obtner todos los elementos mensual y anual por clase
const mensual = document.querySelectorAll('.mensual');
const anual = document.querySelectorAll('.anual');
btnChek.addEventListener('click', function () {
    // Recorrer elementos para mostrar u ocultar
    mensual.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('active'));
    anual.forEach(item => item.classList.toggle('active'));
});
```

```css
.mensual{
    display: block;
}
.anual{
    display: none;
}
  
.mensual.active{
    display: none;
}
.anual.active{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"  class="checkbox">
   <label for="checkbox" class="switch">Anual</label> 
      <div class="card-toggle">
        <p>
          <span class="mensual" >&dollar;39.99</span>
          <span class="anual" >&dollar;399.99</span>
        </p>  
        <ul>
          <li>1 tb libre</li>
          <li>Más espacio en la nube</li>
          <li>ilimitado</li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div id="cards" >
      <div class="card-toggle">
        <p>
          <span class="mensual" >&dollar;59.99</span>
          <span class="anual" >&dollar;599.99</span>
        </p>  
        <ul>
          <li>1 tb libre</li>
          <li>Más espacio en la nube</li>
          <li>ilimitado</li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div>
```